# Roles in Cubes (SSAS)

Tags: sql-server, security, ssas, roles

My current Cube has two roles:

- AdminSec: are for a few users only and refers to a Group of administrators in my Active Directory.
- GlobalSec: refers to "Everyone" and gives everyone access to read all data.

We are now planning to incorporate a new department (MinimalDepartment) in our company. This department should not have access to very much of the information in our company, so my plan is to create a third role (DepartmentSec) and assigning a new Active Directory Group (MinimalDepartment) to this role. Also I will limit the access to my dimension data by deselecting all departments and only grant access to the relevant department in the Department dimension.

My question is: If an employee is a member of the Active Directory Group MinimalDepartment will they then only be able to see the data in the cube which the role DepartmentSec allows (which is what I want)? Or will they be able to see all data as they are also part of "everyone" and therefore also the role GlobalSec?

If it is the latter is it then possible somehow to create the role so "everyone" has access except those in AD-group MinimalDepartment?

Comment: This is an SSAS question, not an SSIS question.

Comment: Yes Tab, you are right! Thanks for changing the necessary for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have to create a new group in my AD which contains all the departments which I want to include and then use this instead of "everyone". Fortunately my IT-supports could tell me that we already have this group so for me its not a problem.